# How to encrypt a parameter file or hide from viewing to all users in unix path in informatica?

Tags: unix, encryption, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I Have a parameter file which I am using in mapping. This file contains credentials and other sensitive information stored as follows:

```
$$username=myusername
$$password=mypassword
$$secret_key=xxxnnccmmmmmz
$$Client_id=ccmmmmlksjsjkl
```

These `$$username` etc.  parameters are defined in the mapping level and used. This parameter file is stored on the unix path which can be accessed by everyone. I need to secure this information in the file, I have heard about AES Encrypt and Decrypt but not have used it . Anyone can explain how this can be achieved and encryption can be done? or can this file be read only for owner, currently it has 775 permissions.

Comment: Usually we try to avoid encryption for passwords, and try to use password hashing (or password based key derivation function, PBKDF) instead. Of course, if possible, try and give as little access as possible to users on the platform; *why* do all the other users have access? Why not use a specialized account?

Comment: its a shared folder all other developers work on it. i use these values in http transformation and get a token which i use in downstream transformation.